# Transitioning run of pipe without reducing flow

Tags: water-pressure

Starting with a collection basin in a small creek using a 1 1/2 inch pipe outlet.  Going downhill 100 ft vertically can I transition to a 1 inch pipe without reducing flow.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Without further information, the answer is almost certainly "no". Are there other limitations on the water flow?

Comment: At a 100 ft water column, you will have a heck of a lot of pressure. I am no engineer, but at 100' you may have something close to a pressure washer out the end.... Better not use PVC, the weight of water in that tall of a column may exceed 300 lbs, maybe not...

Comment: @Jack - please google "head pressure of water column" - the google snippet is actually an example of the pressure of 100' column of water! It will give exactly 43.3 psi. In general, the estimate is 1/2 psi per foot of head/drop. 43.3 psi is totally within the range of many types of pipe schedules.

Comment: 43.3 psi is pretty close to typical city water pressure.

Answer (score 1):

This is really quite simple, even if vaguely asked.

As *@Daniel Griscom* accurately stated in the first comment, "**Almost certainly no**" (so I'm making this a community wiki answer.)

The question asks if reducing the pipe size (at a particular point, but the particular point *does not matter*) can be done *without reducing flow*, and the answer is "no" in basically all cases, though there are some cases where "not enough to matter" would come into play as an answer, but the question does not indicate any information leading to think that is a valid response. In the general case, if there is flow in a pipe, and you reduce the size of the pipe, you increase the total dynamic head and **reduce the flow.** Period.

More information might be helpful if there was a question about "how much would flow be reduced" but that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the length and total flow required. If the length of the reduce pipe is long or you are close to the max flow it would reduce the pressure. If the length of reduced pipe size is short and or you are not demanding more flow that can flow through the smaller pipe you may not see any difference. When no water is flowing the pressure will be the same on a 3" pipe as a 1/4" pipe when there is a flow or more than the small pipe can pass then the pressure will start to drop.

Answer (score 0):

To many unknown variables;
1 What type of pipe? Pvc, PEX and galvanized all have different internal drag coefficients
2. How large is said cistern and location of pipe leading out is it bottom or halfway up? 
3. What is the angle the pipe is running down slope are we talking a 10 degree slope or 60 degrees of slope or do you really mean strait up?
4 Will you need a pressure regulator? Or just planning to blow the seals on every faucet in the house?
5. Are there any bends or angles in the line?
6. Is the cistern pump of pressure assisted?
Pictures, diagrams, maybe a pdf of the plot with elevations would all be good things for us to be able to even give any rational advice.
But good luck and we are always here to help.

Comment: We are fond of correct spelling, paragraphs, and similar formatting to make answers (and questions) comprehensible and readable. Feel free to use the edit link to improve your answer.